# How to use fuzz.ratio on a data frame on pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, fuzzywuzzy

I want to use fuzz.ratio on a data frame, but I'm working on pyspark (I can't use pandas).

I have the function:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
```

I create a data frame like this:

```
communes_corrompues=spark.createDataFrame(
[("VILLEAINTE", "VILLEPINTE"),
('QILLEPINTE'   ,'VILLEPINTE'),
('AHIENS'   ,'AMIENS'),
('AMIEPS'   ,'AMIENS'),
("CVRGY"    ,"CERGY"),
("CERGA"    ,"CERGY")
 ],
    ['corrompue', 'resultat']
)
```

And this sentence doesn't work:

```
communes_corrompues_ratio = communes_corrompues.withColumn("fuzzywuzzy_ratio",
lit(fuzz.ratio(col("resultat"),col("corrompue"))))
```

I have this error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for
> 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean
> expressions.

May someone help me? Or know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try user defined functions for that, something like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

@udf("int")
def fuzz_udf(a,b):
  return fuzz.ratio(a,b)

communes_corrompues_ratio.withColumn("fuzzywuzzy_ratio", fuzz_udf(col("resultat"),col("corrompue")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work! I just change '' @udf("float") " to "@udf("int")".